# Scale an image/view in SwiftUI based on device/screen size

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have the following view in the Max Pro which I am good with

[image]

The issue I am having is that the following screen shot is in an older iPhone 8 model

[image]

How do I scale the elements/view to ensure the same look and feel regardless of device/screen size

Below is my code:

```
VStack() {
        
    HStack {
            
        if (pool.type == "Survivor") {
                    
            Image("survival-football")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 120, height: 90)
                .cornerRadius(10)
                        
        } else {
                    
            Image("pickem-football-small")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 120, height: 90)
                .cornerRadius(10)
         
        }
                
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            
            Spacer()
                    
            Text(pool.name)
                .foregroundColor(Color.textColor)
                .font(.title3)
                .frame(width: 225, alignment: .leading)
                .padding(.bottom, 0.1)
                    
             Text(pool.id)
                .foregroundColor(Color.textColor)
                .font(.system(size: 16))
                    
             Spacer()

        }
        .padding(.leading)
                
        Spacer()
    
    }

}
.padding()
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
.frame(height: 120)
.background(BlurView(style: .regular))
.cornerRadius(10)
.padding(.vertical, 6)
.padding(.horizontal)
```

Comment: Can you please give us some lines of code to see how you've done it?

Comment: Don’t hard code frame values

Comment: Here's what you can do: remove the main `VStack`, remove the 3 `Spacer` and of course remove the `frame` of `Text(pool.name)`. As you use `frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` for the main `HStack` you don't need to use spacers or add a frame to the text views.

Comment: @Alexnnd exact same result!?

Comment: Well, can you create another post with the code, the top part of both screenshots side by side and with a clear description of your problem so we can reply with some code again?